# UK temporary agency worker training full time permanent colleague

Tags: colleagues, hiring-process, ethics, contracts, training

Good evening everyone,

I reside in the UK and I have been working on behalf of an agency for a company on a temporary basis for 6 months now. Recently (2 months ago) a new colleague with no experience was hired on a permanent basis by the company in the role I have been doing for 6 months even though I had applied for the role, the new employee was deemed more suitable due to scoring higher in aptitude tests. However, now the manager and team leader wants me to train the new employee as they are struggling with excel, customs invoices etc.

How do I approach this situation as I am only temporary via agency and they could just use me to train the newer employee up, then say they no longer require me. I'm rather upset and down hearted as they didn't choose me for the role as they believed I didn't meet the standard, but are now asking me to train the individual who got the job over me up.

I really appreciate any sort of advice and guidance on how I can navigate this situation over the next few days.

Thanks C

Comment: Are these excel and customs invoices a core part of the job requirements or just something that has to be dealt with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As upsetting as this may be the company has shown what they think and the decision is complete.

It is up to you if you want to be professional about it and train this new person whilst looking for a new job elsewhere or just storm out the door and put yourself in the difficult position of looking for a job whilst unemployed (which is always much more difficult).

It is always easier to find a new role while already working as you no doubt already know.

Comment: The OP is working with a temp agency, which if anything makes graceful completion of the job even more important.